# Проблема с отправкой запроса в бд

Tags: php

Есть два варианта отправки запроса:

1)

```
$params = [
    'test' => $post['test'],
    'text' => $post['text'],
];

$query = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO test VALUES (:test, :text)', $params);
```

2. 

```
$params = [
    'TITLE' => $post['title'],
    'STRUCTURE' => $post['structure'],
    'TEACHER' => $post['teacher'],
    'HANNIEL' => $post['hanniel'],
    'CLASS' => $post['class'],
];

$query = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO structure VALUES (:TITLE, :STRUCTURE, :TEACHER, :HANNIEL, :CLASS)', $params);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `1` вариант работает, а `2` нет. Не могу понять из-за чего. Никакие ошибки не выводятся, выводится лишь то, что успешно отправлено и т.д. (сделал данный вывод), но в базе, при `2` варианте ничего не появляется.

Comment: Вопросы к автору класса db. Почему он не смог в репортинг ошибок. А так-то проблема очевидна, заполняются не все поля, которые есть в таблице

Comment: Я вводил данные и для всех полей (это был лишь как краткий пример), но почему-то все равно не заполняется, остаются лишь 2 столбца - дата и время, с ними пробовал - тоже самое

Comment: При чем здесь "данные вводил"? Речь про запрос, а не про данные. Посмотри в учебнике, как пишутся запросы insert

Comment: НУ в запрос, в параметры которые отправлял, не ручками в базу данных

Comment: тогда тем более. смотри в учебнике, а не в "варианте который работает" как это делать правильно